# Total value of cards in blackjack

Tags: swift, xctest, blackjack

I'm coding up a blackjack card game to try to slowly get myself back into Swift.

I am trying to get a total value of the cards in a player's hand.

The problem I have is when I come to an ace which can be either 1 or 11, and I'm not sure how to account for this when I do a XCTest against it.

```
// Card model
struct Card {
    
    // Suit enumerated
    enum Suit : Character {
        case spades = "♠", hearts = "♡", diamonds = "♢", clubs = "♣"
    }
    
    // Rank enumerated
    enum Rank : Int {
        case two = 2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
        case jack, queen, king, ace
                    
        struct Values {
            let first: Int, second : Int?
        }
        
        var values: Values {
            switch self {
            case .ace:
                return Values(first: 1, second: 11)
            case .jack, .queen, .king:
                return Values(first: 10, second: nil)
            default:
                return Values(first: self.rawValue, second: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    let rank: Rank, suit : Suit
    
    var value : Rank.Values {
        return self.rank.values
    }
}
```

When I come to test it,

```
// XCTest
func testSumOfCardsEquals21() {
    let card1 = Card(rank: .jack, suit: .diamonds) //10
    let card2 = Card(rank: .four, suit: .diamonds) //4
    let card3 = Card(rank: .three, suit: .diamonds) //3
    let card4 = Card(rank: .ace, suit: .diamonds) //1 or 11
    
    let hand = [card1, card2, card3, card4]
    
    var total = 0
    for card in hand {
        let values = card.value
        if (values.second == nil) {
            total += values.first
        } else {
            let secondValue = values.second!
            total += secondValue
        }
    }
    
    // expected 21
    XCTAssertEqual(total, 21) // this will fail and return 28
}
```

In this scenario you want the ace to be low.

In a scenario where you might just have 1 card (ace) you want it to be high.

I'm not sure how to resolve such a test requirement.

...

To clarify, how do you make a function, test to calculate the total value of the hand of cards to return the expected 21 total when a card can be two values?

I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: The problem is actually more complex than you explain here - you also should accomodate for multiple aces in a hand.  Until you define the rules you can't write an effective test.  For example: is the aim to return the highest value <= 21, using the aces high or low?  And what's the maximum number of aces you can hold (can the game include multiple decks)?

Comment: I didn't think of this, I just thought the check would be one off.  I'll have to rethink it a bit, but I appreciate the signposting towards rules and edge cases informing the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hand makes 18, not 21.

The `Values` type may not be useful—these cards don't really have raw values.

You can't know how to calculate the score without accumulating all of the cards first.

```swift
enum Rank: CaseIterable {
  case two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
  case jack, queen, king
  case ace
}
```

```swift
struct Hand {
  init<Cards: Sequence>(cards: Cards) where Cards.Element == Card {
    let reduction = cards.reduce(into: (score: 0, aceCount: 0)) {
      switch $1.rank {
      case .jack, .queen, .king:
        $0.score += 10
      case .ace:
        $0.score += 1
        $0.aceCount += 1
      default:
        $0.score += try! $1.rank.caseIndex + 2
      }
    }

    var score = reduction.score
    reduction.aceCount.iterations
      .prefix { score <= 12 }
      .forEach { score += 9 }
    self.score = score
  }

  let score: Int
}
```

```swift
Hand(cards: [card1, card2, card3, card4]).score
```

---

```swift
public extension ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral where Self: Strideable, Stride: SignedInteger {
  /// *This many* iterations that produce no values.
  var iterations: LazyMapSequence<Range<Self>, Void> {
    (0..<self).lazy.map { _ in }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
  /// The first match for this case in `allCases`.
  /// - Throws: `AllCasesError<Self>.noIndex`
  var caseIndex: AllCases.Index {
    get throws {
      do { return try Self.allCases.firstIndex(of: self).unwrapped }
      catch { throw AllCasesError.noIndex(self) }
    }
  }
}

public enum AllCasesError<Case: CaseIterable>: Error {
  /// No `AllCases.Index` corresponds to this case.
  case noIndex(Case)
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Represents that an `Optional` was `nil`.
  enum UnwrapError: Error {
    case `nil`
    case typeMismatch
  }

  /// [An alterative to overloading `??` to throw errors upon `nil`.](
  /// https://forums.swift.org/t/unwrap-or-throw-make-the-safe-choice-easier/14453/7)
  /// - Note: Useful for emulating `break`, with `map`, `forEach`, etc.
  /// - Throws: `UnwrapError` when `nil`.
  var unwrapped: Wrapped {
    get throws {
      switch self {
      case let wrapped?:
        return wrapped
      case nil:
        throw UnwrapError.nil
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the partial type inference a 5.6 beta feature?  Better to specify types in the `reduction` for those not on Betas? Nice use of a sequence/iterator though :)

Comment: Except I'm pretty sure 10 + 4 + 3 + 1 is 18, not 19 that `.score` returns.  You're enumerating jack, queen, king to 11, 12, 13 rather than overriding this with 10.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I thought doing it the way I via Values would help associate a value to a card.  I will have to do better in future.